# How to add/sum the desired indexs of an array from specific array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have the following data structure and this data needs to be sorted by the sum of the first two indexes of an array in "104".

```
{
  "data":{
    "Org 1":{
      "102":[
        0.1444,
        0.1551,
        0.2369,
        0.3353,
        0.1282
      ],
      "104":[
        0.309,
        0.3483,
        0.218,
        0.0657,
        0.059
      ]
    },
    "Org 2":{
      "102":[
        0.19444444444444448,
        0.1388888888888889,
        0.19444444444444448,
        0.33333333333333326,
        0.1388888888888889
      ],
      "104":[
        0.20588235294117646,
        0.38235294117647056,
        0.14705882352941177,
        0.14705882352941177,
        0.1176470588235294
      ],
    },
    "Org 3":{
      "102":[
        0.0967741935483871,
        0.2903225806451613,
        0.16129032258064516,
        0.3548387096774194,
        0.0967741935483871
      ],
      "104":[
        0.44,
        0.24,
        0.2,
        0.04,
        0.08
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How can I make this work? Can someone please help?

This is what I tried so far but it's not working as expected

```
let orgs = Object.keys(data);
let options = [];
let selection = orgs.forEach((data, d) => {
  data["104"].forEach((val, i) => {
    options[i].data.push(val);
  })
});
```

Comment: What is the exact output your are going for?

Comment: The first two indexes are always 0 and 1...

Comment: sorted ascending or descending?

Comment: @HereticMonkey sorry, I meant to say values of the first two indexes in array 104 and not the actual index.

Comment: @ZunayedShahriar in ascending order

Comment: @mwilson the expected output I am looking for is when I output the data variable, I see the arrays listed in ascending order based on the sum of the first two index values for each array in the array "104".

Comment: It doesn't make sense to sort an array based on the sum of its elements. And you can't really sort objects, which is what everything except the values of the numerically named properties are...

Comment: @Shaun, check out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we need to **transform** the data into an array for sorting.

Then define our own `compare` function as our requirement.

Finally, sort the array.

Run the snippet to check the result.

**Solution:**

```js
var data = {
  "Org 1":{
    "102":[
      0.1444,
      0.1551,
      0.2369,
      0.3353,
      0.1282
    ],
    "104":[
      0.309,
      0.3483,
      0.218,
      0.0657,
      0.059
    ]
  },
  "Org 2":{
    "102":[
      0.19444444444444448,
      0.1388888888888889,
      0.19444444444444448,
      0.33333333333333326,
      0.1388888888888889
    ],
    "104":[
      0.20588235294117646,
      0.38235294117647056,
      0.14705882352941177,
      0.14705882352941177,
      0.1176470588235294
    ],
  },
  "Org 3":{
    "102":[
      0.0967741935483871,
      0.2903225806451613,
      0.16129032258064516,
      0.3548387096774194,
      0.0967741935483871
    ],
    "104":[
      0.44,
      0.24,
      0.2,
      0.04,
      0.08
    ]
  }
};

const transformedData = [];

Object.keys(data).forEach(
  f => {
    transformedData.push(data[f]);
  }
)

function compare(a, b) {
  var arrA = a["104"];
  var arrB = b["104"];

  if (arrA[0]+arrA[1] < arrB[0]+arrB[1]) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (arrA[0]+arrA[1] > arrB[0]+arrB[1]) {
    return 1;
  }
  
  return 0;
}

transformedData.sort(compare);
console.log(transformedData);
```

**Breakdown:**

```
(0.205882352941176 + 0.38235294117647) < (0.309 + 0.3483) < (0.44 + 0.24)
```

Comment: This does not sort the structure so much as change the structure into one that can be sorted, which is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I'm confused now. Let's see what the OP says about it.